# Check session for each controller and action in symfony2

Tags: symfony

How can we check session for each controller and action in Symfony2. If session is not found redirect it to home page. I can check session in each action but i think it is not the best way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your own [listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) which listens the [kernel.request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request) event and do your logic. Short example:

```
class KernelListener
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $responseEvent)
    {
        $request = $responseEvent->getRequest();

        if (!$request->getSession()->has(YOUR_KEY)) {
            $responseEvent->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('HOME_PAGE_ROUTE')));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not implemented the above code but i think it is the best way to check the session in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there have a built-in special functionality to check this option in every controller and action. but i think its possible to do it by putting the session check code in each controllers constructor or in initialising method.

```
class ControllerName
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      //session checking code
   }    
}
```